# What is the Best Practice to check billing plan payments using PayPal REST API SDK?

Tags: api, paypal, sdk, billing

I have managed to successfully create billing `plans` and `agreements` by using `PayPal PHP SDK` via REST API for the Web Service of company I work. However I could not find any document about how I should check the agreement payments made automatically.

I guess the `webhooks` are for this work but also I can retrieve the payment transactions via SDK.

There are the cons of both.

- Con of using webhooks is that the website really should work all the time and there is no way to understand if I have missed a request. This is something I can not guarantee for all moment.
- Con of using REST API, I should check for all the `transaction`s of all `agrements` to sync with my DB.

Is there a better solution that I possibly miss or are those the only possible solutions.

What would be the best practice for checking received or missed plan payment?

Comment: You should also be able to use IPNs. Old-fashioned, but they should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversation on https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/69 would be relevant to you. Short answer is that while support for billing agreements in webhooks is underway, using IPN would be the best interim solution if you want to be push notified, else transactions of all agreements would need to be fetched.

Comment: Thank you for pointing a way. I will share the results after implimentation.